# Installing Boost v1.70 in Visual Studio 2019 using Nuget

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019

I'm learning C++, some of the Boost libraries and VS2019 Community Edition. I'm currently reading through the Boost website's online material and the book *Learning Boost C++ Libraries*, trying to follow along.  I would like to update to 1.70.0 and figure out exactly why my code is building correctly.  I know, I know...if it's working why question it?  Well, the truth is I just don't understand why!

I wasn't aware of Nuget and vcpkg prior to downloading and installing Boost 1.68.0 manually (BTW, there seems to be way too many ways of installing the libraries and it's quite confusing).  I have since deleted the original Boost installation directory and tried to install the Boost libraries through Nuget in VS2019.  This didn't appear to be successful (although I suspect vcpkg (see below) has something to do with it).  I was getting a single linker error (can't find the .lib file) which I eventually resolved (don't ask me how...it's a confusing story involving creating a new project and cutting/pasting my code.  Now it works; go figure).

Currently, when I begin an #include directive () in my code I can see the path to the files which is buried under D:\...\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost.  I've never used vcpkg directly so I have no idea why it's there.  The Property Pages for the project don't list the paths under **C/C++ > Additional Include Directories** or under **Linker > Additional Library Directories** so I haven't a clue from where the compiler and linker are getting the references.  There appear to be no packages installed under the Nuget UI.

Ideally, I would like to start over with the Boost installation and use VS internal tools to do so.  I will probably have several different VS solutions as I explore Boost and would prefer Boost to be available to all future projects.  Is that possible?

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that the "boost" package only installs the header only libraries, it doesn't install all the libraries that require a binary library.

To install the binary libraries, you need to install individual packages, for instance "boost_log-vc141" is the boost logging library.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the `boost` package into your project using NuGet. You should see a `packages.config` added to your project that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="boost" version="1.70.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

Next, include the desired boost header file:

```
#include <boost\array.hpp>
```

You can confirm that the header is being loaded from the correct path by placing the caret after the `hpp`, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, then hovering hovering over the item in the context list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Opened Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and searched for boost.  Installed "boost-vc142" which appeared to run successfully since I got the package.config file in the solution.

However, when I build the solution I get a linker error: 

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_70.lib'

Also, I get two entries with different paths in the context list for each of the #includes.